# Laravel - Placeholder is not fully/properly displayed

Tags: placeholder, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7.
I have defined a variable $input_placeholder (value = "Your Name") in a controller and I am passing this variable onto a view ("create view", blade).
I am trying to access the variable from the view (fron an input placeholder), but the value displayed is not right. Only the first word is displayed (ex: only "Your" is displayed).
What am I missing here?

**Route File:**

```
Route::get('/create','HomeController@create')->name('create');
```

**create view:**

```
@extends('layouts.form')

    @section('form_content')  
    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder={{$input_placeholder}} class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
        </div>
    </form>
    @endsection
```

**Create() function in controller:**

```
{
    public function create()
    {
        $data=[
            'input_placeholder' => 'Your Name'
        ];
        //no need for an array in this example but ultimately yes
        return view('create')->with($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind, I found my mistake, `{{$input_placeholder}}` in between `" "` like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="{{$input_placeholder}}" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
```

I am leaving the question because I was not able to find a solution to my problem in StackOverflow. Therefore, I think it could be useful to other beginner-struggler like me.

If you think this question is not usefull, **please let me know in a comment** and I will delete it.